# latest ios Builds not showing under Testflight

Tags: ios, build, version, app-store-connect, testflight

I have go live app on app store with details 
version - 0.0.1
build - 0.0.19

added many UAT version after that now the last version was 1.0.1 with build 0.0.24

Now i have uploaded build for production with below details but i am unable see this app in testflight for testing.
version - 0.0.2
build - 0.0.1

is it because of build version? please suggest.

Comment: When you upload your latest build on app store is that build visible in activity tab and suddenly stopped showing, in this way it happened??

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. It was solved. build was not showing up in testflight app in mobile. tried to open the app in other mobile with user who has admin rights and opened the previous builds. it was there.

Comment: Okay Great !!!!